# Add points in Chart.js/Chart asp.net from background vb code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, chart.js

I'm trying to develop trend/chart on asp.net with charts.js. I am able to draw chart and update that dynamically.

I am adding y-axis of chart based on point array (highlighted below). I like to add that array from background vb code.  Please help me to do that.

FYI : I cannot able to add asp textbox or label on designer because I have developed that in javascript.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext('2d');

var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
***var points = [1001, 1002, 1003];***
var updates = 0;
var maxdatapoints = 60;
var pointsHub = $.connection.pointsHub;


pointsHub.client.pointsUpdate = function (points) {
    updates += 1;
    var dat = Date.now();
    $.each(points, function (i, elem) {
        var data = chart.data.datasets[i].data;
        if (updates > maxdatapoints) {
            data.shift();
        }
        data.push({ x: dat, y: elem.NumValue });
    });
    chart.update();
}
```